# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django website won't show up

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set Elastic Beanstalk of Python3.6/Amazon Linux with Django 1.11.
The application has been successfully uploaded via EB CLI and installed.

```
INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
```

set .config files without errors:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myproject.settings
    SECRET_KEY: TempKey

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myproject/wsgi.py
```

The EB parses wsgi.py well.

I have included the current EB address(like projectname.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) in ALLOWED_HOSTS.

After all these 'no-error' processes, however, the actual website does not show up. (while, the EB sample application was working) There is even no 400, 500 error message page at all. No Django error message no matter what DEBUG=True or False. Just browser shows a blank timed out page.

When I run Django in local environment with `python manage.py runserver`, it works nicely.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3150] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[suexec:notice] [pid 20456] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[so:warn] [pid 20456] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[http2:warn] [pid 20456] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[http2:warn] [pid 20456] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20456] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[:warn] [pid 20456] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[:warn] [pid 20456] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20456] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 20456] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'


-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)
INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 20456
INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_myproject_test_1/Test for Command 01_migrate] : Completed activity. Result:
  
  Completed successfully.
  Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, .....
  Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
 
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /opt/python/ondeck/app.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 0 completed
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.py] : Completed activity. Result:
  httpd: stopped
  httpd: started
  httpd                            RUNNING   pid 20456, uptime 0:00:03
INFO     Apache is running, but root page is not responding in 3 seconds.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02create_pids_for_monitoring.sh] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02create_pids_for_monitoring.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + chmod 0755 /var/run/httpd
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --name application --location /opt/python/run/supervisord.pid
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/PostInitHook/01processmgrstart.sh] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/PostInitHook/01processmgrstart.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + pgrep supervisord
  3064
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 1 completed
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2021-01-01T05:23:11.925Z] INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
INFO  [20664] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...


-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
INFO  [3223]  : Instance is Leader.
DEBUG [3223]  : Loaded 7 actions for stage 0.
INFO  [3223]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-Startup...
DEBUG [3223]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 1.
INFO  [3223]  : Command CMD-Startup succeeded!
INFO  [3223]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
DEBUG [20664] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
DEBUG [20664] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
DEBUG [20664] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-007e4078e1a342421)..
INFO  [20664] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-007e4078e1a342421)..
DEBUG [20664] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
INFO  [20664] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
INFO  [20664] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data"=>"*", "instance_ids"=>["i-007e4078e1a342421"], "data"=>"dfd6c391-1fa0-433d-916d-2696608b221a", "command_name"=>"CMD-TailLogs", "api_version"=>"1.0", "resource_name"=>"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup", "request_id"=>"dfd6c391-1fa0-433d-916d-2696608b221a"}
INFO  [20664] : Command processor should execute command.
DEBUG [20664] : Storing current stage..
DEBUG [20664] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
DEBUG [20664] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
DEBUG [20664] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
DEBUG [20664] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
INFO  [20664] : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
INFO  [20664] : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
INFO  [20664] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
DEBUG [20664] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
DEBUG [20664] : Setting environment variables..
```

Some suspicious parts are below:

```
INFO  [3223]  - [Application deployment app-51cc-29999@52/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.py] : Completed activity. Result:
  httpd: stopped
  httpd: started
  httpd                            RUNNING   pid 20456, uptime 0:00:03
INFO     Apache is running, but root page is not responding in 3 seconds.
```

and,

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"

I tried manually restarting httpd on EC2 SSH, refreshing the EB Environment and application, using https and HTTP, using EC2 IP address, and restarting from the scratch but they didn't work.

Is there any clue to fix the problem?

Comment: If you ssh to the EB instance, can you curl your app from inside to confirm it works as expected?

Comment: @Marcin doing `curl -L 127.0.0.1` shows the source of a Django page. The message is : Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. But the error message is the same even after added 127.0.0.1, localhost to the ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: Just for the quick temp testing, if you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]` does it change anything?

Comment: @Marcin Okay.. now it shows `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused`. Same with port 443. (httpd is running) Weired thing's that even I undo changing `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, it still says refused.

Comment: Port 80 will be httpd/nginx port. What about your dinago app port (default is 8000)?